# apache rewrite rule with parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following url:

```
http://www.domain.com/results.php?state=WA&city=Seattle&sub=algebra
```

I would like it to appear as:

```
http://www.domain.com/results/WA/Seattle/algebra
```

And...

```
http://www.domain.com/results.php?state=WA&city=Seattle
```

as

```
http://www.domain.com/results/WA/Seattle
```

I figure I could write the first as:

```
RewriteRule ^results/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  /results.php?state=$1&city=$2&sub=$3 [L]
```

but I'm stuck figuring out how to combine both of them... the slashes are throwing me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$  /results.php?state=$1&city=$2&sub=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^results/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /results.php?state=$1&city=$2
```

Comment: so if the [L] is there and the longest possibility is first it will stop the process after that line?

Comment: what is the difference between ([^/]) and (.*)

Comment: see the edit. I have used + to ensure that any parameter is not empty. so if the url is of first match then it will not match the second kind. Also the url of second kind will not match the first because of [^/]

Comment: [^/] means any character other than /. + means one or more of [^/]